# tf.exe checkin only included pending changes

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, tf-cli

I have a batch file that will checkin my pending changes using tf.exe, but it checks in all pending changes. I'm trying to find a way to only checkin *included* pending changes in VS2015 and leave excluded files alone.

Here's what I have:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" checkin /comment:"%*" /noprompt`

I read the [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=vs.100).aspx) but couldn't find anything related to included/excluded files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Included and excluded files seems to be a purely client concept in Visual Studio rather than something the workspace is made aware of, so I don't believe there would be any way that TF could know which are included.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm just trying to not checkin web.configs and can't seem to get a .tfignore file to work, otherwise this wouldn't be an issue.